# missing ';' before namespace when using boost 1.4.2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

Working on moving some C++ code from Linux over to Windows.  The code uses boost 1.4.2, however it keeps failing out on building the boost modules. Basically, every boost hpp file that happens to contain "namespace boost" errors with:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'namespace'
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: "ASNI compliant C code" - but boost is a C++ library!

Comment: Yeah... I was doing ansi C for something else earlier...oops, fixed now.

Comment: Can you post a minimal sample of code that demonstrates the error? After all, when you have a syntax error, it often helps to inspect the *syntax*. Also, do you mean Boost 1.42? 1.4.2 would be *very* old.

Answer (score 5):

Loss of `;` before including Boost header could be cause of that. The following code produce such error:

```
struct X {}  // << ; lost here

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

This small code gives me the following error:

```
boost/config/suffix.hpp(460) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'namespace'
```

Comment: The error is showing up about 20 levels down in the includes tree... any tips on how to find the missing ;?
Also... this code compiles on Linux, I haven't changed it.

Comment: Check my sample. It produces the error somewhere in `suffix.hpp`. To locate the error just print `;` before first include of Boost headers. Move `;` up until you find place where it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including these boost headers on the first line? If they compile fine that way, it's likely a missing `;` in one of the headers included before them.